# grouplike elements in a completion

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $G$ be a derived $p$-complete abelian group and $K$ a field.
Let $\widehat{K[G]}$ denote the completion of the group ring $K[G]$ at the augmentation ideal.
Is there a nice description of the set of grouplike elements in $\widehat{K[G]}$?